# Как отключить поддержку .webp в Хроме?

Tags: html, google-chrome, изображения, webp

Как можно отключить поддержку .webp формата изображения, дабы Хром не предлагал мне скачать изображение в этом расширении вместо привычного .jpg? Так, например, сделано в Огнелисе. Позволено ли так же сделать в Хроме?

Comment: Ни хром, ни Огнелис ничего сами не переделывают и предлагают строго только то, что сервер отдаёт браузеру. Отдаёт webp — значит будет webp. Отдаёт jpeg — значит будет jpeg. О деталях поведения спрашивайте у администратора сервера, а не у нас

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Webp и jpg - РАЗНЫЕ форматы файлов и браузер НЕ МОЖЕТ загрузить webp как jpg, поскольку не оснащен встроенным конвертером изображений.
2. Огнелис не делает ничего подобного. Если вам вместо .webp приходит .jpg, значит, разработчик сайта предусмотрел старый браузер и подкладывает вам картинку в поддерживаемом формате.
3. Соответственно, в Хроме не нужно ничего отключать. Не нравится webp - пользуйтесь браузером, его не поддерживающим, и надейтесь, что автор сайта озаботился подложить jpg-версии картинок. Впрочем, теоретически вы можете заставить Хром представляться сайтам как Firefox, поменяв ему User-agent, ну а дальше... дальше остается тоже надеяться.